# How can I access DWORDs from a TBytes array?

Tags: arrays, delphi, casting

I have a `TBytes` array and I want to access it like an array of `DWORD`, but I don't want to make a new copy of the `TBytes` array. I tried to typecast it but the Length of the new variable has the same Length as the old one, not `Length(TBytes)/4` as it should. And if I want to set the correct length, Delphi makes a copy of it and the connection between the two arrays is lost. It is possible to make it work ?

Comment: Use a pointer variable of type PDWORD then `p := @arr[0];` to read the first four bytes as a dword. `Inc(p)` to point to the next 4 bytes.

Comment: Declare type `TDWords = array of DWord;` then use `absolute` directive: `var MyBytesArray: TBytes; MyDWordsArray: TDWords absolute MyBytesArray;`

Comment: @Abelisto: using `absolute` in that manner will get you access to the `DWORD` values, but `Length(MyDWordsArray)` won't return the correct number of `DWORD`s, it will return `Length(MyBytesArray)` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed. From other side it allows to keep arrays together after the possible relocation of the `TBytes` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get a pointer to the array data and then type-cast it.  Simply type-casting the pointer does not change the fact that you are still pointing at an array of bytes, that is why the length is the same.  You have to manually calculate the number of `DWORD`s by dividing the array length by 4.

Try this:

```
var
  bytes: TBytes;
  values, value: LPDWORD;
  i, numValues: Integer;  
begin
  // populate bytes as needed...
  values := LPDWORD(bytes);
  value := values;
  numValues := Length(bytes) div sizeof(DWORD);
  for I := 0 to numValues-1 do
  begin
    // use value^ as needed...
    Inc(value);
  end;
end;
```

Or, if you are using Delphi 2009+:

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}

var
  bytes: TBytes;
  values: LPDWORD;
  i, numValues: Integer;  
begin
  // populate bytes as needed...
  values := LPDWORD(bytes);
  numValues := Length(bytes) div sizeof(DWORD);
  for I := 0 to numValues-1 do
  begin
    // use values[i] as needed...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. It works verry nicely, but we must take care, if we are increasing the size of the byte array, to update the pointer again because the array is relocated at a new address. Anyway, it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an additional type:

```
TIEEE754Float = record
  case Boolean of   // Access to the same memory area
    True:
      (Byte1, Byte2, Byte3, Byte4: Byte);   // As 4 bytes
    False:
      (Float: Single);  // As 32-bit float
end;
```

I am using it for the MODBUS communication

```
procedure TestTModbusRtu.TestWriteFrame;
const
  KS_45_ADDRESS = 2;
  DEVICE_ADDRESS = KS_45_ADDRESS;
  FUNCTION_CODE = TFunctionCode.fcWriteMultipleRegisters;
  MEMORY_ADDRESS = 16472;   // Set target temperature
  EXPECTED_VALUE = 45.5;
var
  frame: TFrame;
  value: TIEEE754Float;
begin
  frame.DeviceAddress := DEVICE_ADDRESS;
  frame.FunctionCode := FUNCTION_CODE;

  frame.DataArray[0] := MEMORY_ADDRESS div 256;   // Addresse (High Bit)
  frame.DataArray[1] := MEMORY_ADDRESS mod 256;   // Addresse (Low Bit)
  frame.DataArray[2] := 0;  // Anzahl des Wertes (High)
  frame.DataArray[3] := 2;  // Anzahl des Wertes (Low)
  frame.DataArray[4] := 4;  // Anzahl des Bytes geschickt

  value.Float := EXPECTED_VALUE;

  frame.DataArray[5] := value.Byte4;
  frame.DataArray[6] := value.Byte3;
  frame.DataArray[7] := value.Byte2;
  frame.DataArray[8] := value.Byte1;

  PrepareModbusRtuConnection(fModbusRtu);
  fModbusRtu.Connect;
  try
    fModbusRtu.WriteFrame(frame);

    ...

  finally
    fModbusRtu.Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```